# How to overwrite the database name set in the .sql file when importing

Tags: mysql

Well I have .sql files which create their own new database when importing because they

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `something` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET$ USE `something`;
```

i'm importing it with

```
mysql -u root -p --database=something_else < something.sql
```

database something_else is already created but it still import it in new dabase called something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iam not a sql guru, but edit the file and remove the create database command, and change reference to the name to your db name, as for the use command to be sure it reflect your db name

Comment: Can I just edit those .sql files in nano?

Comment: @user240891 Yes, I did that in the past, in notepad in windows, but was to reflect the good db name too.